# Call an Activity by using Click on SideBar Navigation Menu Item

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-side-navigation

How to Call an Activity while using Side Navigation in Android.

I am using this sample :Navigation menu for Android (based off Google+ app)

https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu

Here i want, whenever user will click on **Home** then need to call *CategoryActivity* and when do click on **Home2** then need to call *OptionsActivity* and so on.....

**RibbonsampleActivity.Java:**

```
public class RibbonsampleActivity extends Activity implements iRibbonMenuCallback {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private RibbonMenuView rbmView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        rbmView = (RibbonMenuView) findViewById(R.id.ribbonMenuView1);
        rbmView.setMenuClickCallback(this);
        rbmView.setMenuItems(R.menu.ribbon_menu);     
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            rbmView.toggleMenu();
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void RibbonMenuItemClick(int itemId) {
        // Handle item selection

    }
         }
```

**ribbon_menu.xml:**

```
 <menu
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/ribbon_menu_home" android:title="Home" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/ribbon_menu_home2" android:title="Home2" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/ribbon_menu_home3" android:title="Home3" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
```

I want to call activities by using particular Side Bar Navigation Item:

*Home > CategroyActivity*

*Home2 > OptionsActivity*

*Home3 > ArrowActivity*

Comment: replace this line  rbmView.setMenuClickCallback(RibbonsampleActivity.this); in Oncreate(..);

Answer (score 0):

you have got a null pointer in `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

`getActionBar()` returns null. there could be couple of reasons for this, most probably this could be an issue of your project setup. check your AndroidManifest.xml and remove if you have set a "fullscreen" or "no title bar" theme.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Solution for this problem is you need to use Fragment instead of Activity.
Best Example here: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/